# how to avoid list index out of range

Tags: python

```
def most_popular_guests(file_in):
    f=file(file_in,'r')
    listoflines=f.readlines()
    D={}
    dict={}
    title=''

    for lines in listoflines:
        if (lines.isupper()):
            title=lines
        else: 
            lines=lines.split(":")
            names=(lines[1]).split(",")
        for name in names:
            if D.has_key(name):
                D[name].append(Show_Appearance(title,lines[0]))
            else:
                D[name]=[Show_Appearance(title,lines[0])]
                break

    dict=longest(D)


def longest(D):    
    max=0
    d={}
    for name in D.keys():
        value = D[name]
        if max<len(value):
            max=len(value)

    for keys in D.keys:
        value=D[keys]
        if len(value)==max:
            d[key]=value

    return d
```

i am trying to find a dictionary with the most frequent appeared person as the key, and the list of shows of that person as the values. keeping this list index out of range error.

Comment: Is the error coming from the `names=(lines[1]).split(",")` line? That would suggest that there's a line without `:` in it, so `lines.split(":")` would be of length 1.

Comment: without knowing the content of the input file, it is rather hard to find out exact where went wrong. Can you provide a sample input and the error trace in the terminal?

Comment: Don't name your variable `dict` as in `dict={}` There is no need to set `title=''` since every string is unmuteable and you will not be appending to it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the traceback. Always post the full error message in cases such as these.

Comment: @carrot-top - I think you mean "immutable" :)

Comment: @detly: Ya Ya dats it! "immutable" Spelling was never my strongest trait...

Comment: My problem with this question is in how it is phrased; its about finding a bug in this application, not strategies for accessing a list within bounds.

Answer (score 3):

The general problem with the script is that it makes wrong assumptions and is not prepared to deal with the situation when the assumptions turn out to be incorrect :)

More specifically, `lines.split(":")` is not guaranteed to return a list which is at least 2 elements long, while the rest of the code just blindly assumes it is safe to access lines[0] and lines[1].

How exactly to deal with this depends on your goals - you may want to ignore such input, stop the script or maybe to log a warning. Something like this will skip the lines which have wrong format:

```
        lines=lines.split(":")
        if len(lines) < 2:
            print "Woops, bad line: %s" % lines
            continue
```